# when i download a file from uploaded files and when i open it it is not opening correctly..image or data in text file is not dispalying

Tags: php

I follow all steps mentioned in the link given below to upload file add file,list file and get file...All things are going fine..But i have one problem When i download the file(it is downloaded no problem) but when i open it then file is not opening..Like suppose i have downloaded an image then after download if i try to open it erro is photogallry can not open this,may be file format is not supported..I am using window vista..So plz tell me where i am falling wrong...I alos passes headed in get file so that my browser can know what type file is this..In following link i used mysql rather than mysql ietc.

Headers passed are..

```
header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['name']);
```

The link for tutorial is

http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php/2#post3541329

Now tell me please what is this problem and how i can download file without any error..I also without using headers but then only temporaray name is displaying beacus in data variable i am storing temproary name

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the length is set correctly. You probably don't need the `header("Content-length: ...");` part. Here is an example of how to download a file with PHP: [PHP outputting file attachments with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896178/php-outputting-file-attachments-with-headers)